# How can I automate a HTTP request to click a button and automate checking out on a shopify site

Tags: javascript, http, request, shopify

Alright so basically,
I can post to this website http://elementalknives.com like this

```
http://elementalknives.com/cart/21977860165:1?
checkout[email]=x@outlook.com
&checkout[shipping_address][first_name]=XXX
&checkout[shipping_address][last_name]=XXX
&checkout[shipping_address][address1]=XXXXX
&checkout[shipping_address][city]=England
&checkout[shipping_address][province]=Arizona
&checkout[shipping_address][zip]=85001
&checkout[shipping_address][phone]=07129151286
&checkout[shipping_address][country]=United States
```

and when I goto this link, all the textboxes I need to be filled are full, the next step would be clicking 'continue to shipping method', and I'm wondering how I will simulate clicking the button 'continue to shipping method', I know it posts to the same url with
    ?previous_step=contact_information&step=shipping_method

, however the data I posted above already wouldn't be stored for example all the textboxes, so when i post like this

```
http://elementalknives.com/cart/21977860165:1?
checkout[email]=x@outlook.com
&checkout[shipping_address][first_name]=XXX
&checkout[shipping_address][last_name]=XXX
&checkout[shipping_address][address1]=XXXXX
&checkout[shipping_address][city]=England
&checkout[shipping_address][province]=Arizona
&checkout[shipping_address][zip]=85001
&checkout[shipping_address][phone]=07129151286
&checkout[shipping_address][country]=United States
&previous_step=contact_information
&step=shipping_method
```

It says 'Please enter your shipping information.'

I assume this is because it doesn't save the text boxes values ?

How would I save these values and submit that so it takes me to the next page?

If I goto the original POSTED URL, and I click the continue button it takes me to the next step, so I'm unsure how I will do this.

Here is what my code looks like

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var formData = { 
                'checkout[email]': 'X@outlook.com',
                'checkout[shipping_address][first_name]': 'XXX',
                'checkout[shipping_address][last_name]': 'XXX',
                'checkout[shipping_address][company]': '',
                'checkout[shipping_address][address1]': 'XXX Road',
                'checkout[shipping_address][address2]': '',
                'checkout[shipping_address][city]': 'XXX',
                'checkout[shipping_address][country]': 'United States',
                'checkout[shipping_address][province]': 'Arizona',
                'checkout[shipping_address][zip]': '85001',
                'checkout[shipping_address][phone]': '07129151286',
                'previous_step': 'contact_information',
                'step': 'shipping_method'
               };

request({
    headers: { 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1' }, url: 'http://elementalknives.com/cart/21977860165:1', form: formData, method: 'GET' },
    function (err, res, body) {
        fs.writeFile("temp.html", body, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        }); 
    }
);
```

I currently save the file to see if it successfully took me to the next stage, however it always never posts successfully and thinks I haven't inputted the shipping method when I post the same as them. I have taken a look at the cookies and there is no difference when it goes from the contact_information step to the shipping_method, so I'm confused

Comment: [Shopify API](https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/reference)?

Comment: Shopify do not have an API for this :(